# Why does randomstring give different values for the same constant?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I don't think I reassigned the value to the constant, verificationcode and perhaps verificationimg which is based off verificationcode.

The code should send a DM with the verificationcode in an image to the user if user uses the command without args, and should give user a role if the user successfully enters the latest generated verificationcode, as well as reply with a success message. However, even when typing in the verificationcode as seen from the image, the bot still replied that the code is wrong. I tried to add checkmymoney but now it doesn't work either.

This is my code:

Sorry if the answer is obvious I cannot think of the solution and I am noob at programming.

```js
const { prefix } = require('../config.json');

module.exports = {
    name: 'verify',
    description: 'This command allows you to verify yourself',
    aliases: ['verification'],
    usage: 'without arguments to get verification code and with verification code to verify',
    cooldown: 5,
    execute(message, args) {
        const data = [];
        const Discord = require('discord.js');
        const { commands } = message.client;

        const member = message.author;
        
        const randomString =  require('random-string')
        const verificationcode = randomString({
            length: 6,
            numeric: true,
            letters: false,
            special: false,
        });
 

        const verificationimg = `https://flamingtext.com/net-fu/proxy_form.cgi?imageoutput=true&script=supermarket-logo&text=${verificationcode}&doScale=true&scaleWidth=240&scaleHeight=120&backgroundRadio=2&backgroundPattern=Purple+Glow`

        if (!args.length) {

            const verificationEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor("#0000FF")
                .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true}))
                .setTitle("Verification Image")
                .setDescription(`Please do \`verify (code shown in image)\` in the server to verify yourself and gain access to rest of server. If the image is not loading, use this link: \`${verificationimg}\``)
                .setTimestamp()
                .setImage(verificationimg)
                .setFooter("MikuBot verification");

            
            return message.author.send(verificationEmbed)
                .then(() => {
                    if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return;
                        message.reply('Check your DMs for the verification code');
                        console.log(`User ${message.author.tag} requested for verification code.`);
                    })
    
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error(`Could not send verification DM to ${message.author.tag}.\n`, error);
                        message.reply(`The DM couldn't get through. Please ensure that 1) You have DMs enabled for this server 2) You allow me to send DMs to you. If error persists, contact a @Helper for assistance.`);
                });
        }
        
        

        else if (args.length) {
           let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'test');
           const userMessage = args
           if (verificationcode === undefined) {
               return message.channel.send (`Please use \`!verify\` without arguments first to generate your verification code.`)
           }
           else if (userMessage === "checkmycode") {
                return message.channel.send(verificationcode)
            }
           else if (verificationcode != userMessage) {
               return message.channel.send (`Verification code is wrong! Please try again`)
           }
           else if (verificationcode === userMessage) {
                if(role) message.member.roles.add(role);
                message.channel.type === 'dm'
                return message.channel.send(`You have been successfully verified in **OwO Server**`)
           }
        
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code a lot by removing unused variables, removing useless statements, moving chunks of code, fixing indentation and fixing the verification functionality.

I fixed the verification code issue by creating a new collection using `const codes = new Discord.Collection();` at the start of the file, and adding in verification codes which are associated with user IDs. Since the variable was declared outside the function, it maintains its value and therefore, you don't get the issue of a new code being generated that doesn't match the old code.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const randomString =  require('random-string');

const codes = new Discord.Collection();

module.exports = {
  name: 'verify',
  description: 'This command allows you to verify yourself',
  aliases: ['verification'],
  usage: 'without arguments to get verification code and with verification code to verify',
  cooldown: 5,
  execute(message, args) {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    
    if (!args.length) {
      codes.set(message.user.id, randomString({
        length: 6,
        numeric: true,
        letters: false,
        special: false
      }));

      const img = 'https://flamingtext.com/net-fu/proxy_form.cgi?imageoutput=true&script=supermarket-logo&text='
      + verificationcode
      + '&doScale=true&scaleWidth=240&scaleHeight=120&backgroundRadio=2&backgroundPattern=Purple+Glow';

      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#0000FF')
        .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
        .setTitle('Verification Code')
        .setDescription('Please type `!verify <code in image>` to verify yourself and access the rest of the server.'
          + 'If the image is not loading, use this link instead: `' + img + '`.')
        .setTimestamp()
        .setImage(img)
        .setFooter('MikuBot verification');
      
      return message.author.send(embed)
        .then(() => {
          message.reply('Please check your DMs for the verification code');
          console.log('User ' + message.author.tag + ' requested a verification code.');
        }).catch(err => {
          message.reply('An error occurred when sending a DM. Please ensure that '
            + '1) You have DMs enabled for this server '
            + '2) You allow me to send DMs to you.'
            + 'If the error persists, please contact a @Helper for assistance.');
          console.error('Could not send a verification DM to ' + message.author.tag + ': ' + err);
        });
    } else {
      const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'test');

      const subcommand = args[0];

      if (codes.has(message.user.id)) {
        if (subcommand === 'checkmycode') {
          return message.reply(codes.get(message.user.id));
        } else if (subcommand === codes.get(message.user.id)) {
          if (role) message.member.roles.add(role);

          codes.delete(message.user.id);

          return message.reply('You have successfully been verified in **OwO Server**.');
        }
      } else {
        return message.reply('Please use `!verify` without arguments first to generate your verification code.');
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When the user first call your function you generate a code but you don't store it, so when user call the function a second time with arg you generate a second code that is different from the first.